# AutoMapper cannot resolve Object from JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

So I am having an issue using AutoMapper to resolve my Cart items from the database where they are stored as a string. I am using a passing a CustomerCartDto to the front-end. When I manually map the properties everything works but I can't seem to get AutoMapper to recognize how to map the the items.

This is what I have in the controller. I have commented out the manual mapping below that works. The mapper function above that code block is what throws the error.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerCartDto>> GetCurrentUserCart()
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindUserByClaimsPrinciple(HttpContext.User);
    var cart = await _unitOfWork.Carts.GetCartAsync(user);
    await _unitOfWork.Complete();
    var returnedCart = _mapper.Map<CustomerCart, CustomerCartDto>(cart);

    // var returnedCart = new CustomerCartDto
    // {
    //   Id = cart.Id,
    //    Username = cart.AppUser.UserName,
    //    Email = cart.AppUser.Email,
    //    Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartItemDto>>(cart.Items)
    //};

    return Ok(returnedCart);
}
```

I have the mapping profiles pulled out into another file here:

```cs
CreateMap<CustomerCart, CustomerCartDto>()
.ForMember(d => d.Items, o => o.MapFrom<CartItemsFromJsonResolver>())
.ForMember(d => d.Username, o => o.MapFrom(d => d.AppUser.UserName))
.ForMember(d => d.Username, o => o.MapFrom(d => d.AppUser.Email));
```

Because I am mapping from a JSON string to a class I have the actually resolver in another function here:

```cs
public class CartItemsFromJsonResolver: IValueResolver<CustomerCart, CustomerCartDto, List<CartItemDto>>
{
    public CartItemsFromJsonResolver()
    {
        //
    }
    
    public List<CartItemDto> Resolve(CustomerCart source, CustomerCartDto destination, List<CartItemDto> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Items))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartItemDto>>(source.Items);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I said if I manually map the properties in my controller and don't use AutoMapper it works fine without any issues but I would like to keep my controller as skinny as possible.  Here is the error that gets thrown out in Postman.
[Image of Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmjoa.png)

**Edit :** Here are the class being used:

```cs
public class CustomerCartDto
{
    public CustomerCartDto(AppUser appUser, List<CartItemDto> items)
    {
        Items = items;
        Username = appUser.UserName;
    }
    
    public CustomerCartDto(AppUser appUser, List<CartItemDto> items, string id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Items = items;
        Username = appUser.UserName;
    }

    public CustomerCartDto()
    {
        //
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }  
    public string Username { get; set; }    
    public string Email { get; set; }   
    public List<CartItemDto> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And also how the model stored in the DB -

```cs
public class CustomerCart
{
    public string Id { get; set; }  
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }    
    public string Items { get; set; }   
    // public float Subtotal { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: Can you include the definitions of the types being mapped?

Comment: I think your types are wrong. The source type would be a string. If you look at the error you posted, it's trying to map each character in the string to an itemDto which is probably happening because you are resolver isn't applicable

Comment: I have the source type set as a string both in the model as well as the resolver.

Comment: This is an example of what the data looks like in the DB. 
`[
  {
    "Id": "25081b74-812c-4f9c-a727-a771b3a14cc9",
    "AppUserId": "aecb9982-2a28-482a-96ca-2538aeb675af",
    "Items": "[{\"ISBN\":\"123-4-521-12345-7\",\"Price\":16.99,\"Description\":\"A beautiful christmas story.\",\"Title\":\"Christmas Time\",\"PictureUrl\":\"https://localhost:5001/assets/images/christmas.jpg\",\"Quantity\":2}]"
  },
] `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `IValueResolver` is supposed to work in AutoMapper mapping configuration, but since your manual mapping works just fine, I'm assuming this line -

```cs
Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartItemDto>>(cart.Items)
```

in your manual mapping is doing it's job as expected.

If so, then changing your current mapping configuration to following should solve your issue -

```cs
CreateMap<CustomerCart, CustomerCartDto>()
.ForMember(d => d.Username, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AppUser.UserName))
.ForMember(d => d.Username, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AppUser.Email))
.AfterMap((s, d) =>
{
    d.Items = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<List<CartItemDto>>(s.Items);
});
```

Let us know if your issue still remains.

**Edit :**
And also, rename `Items` property to something else in either `CustomerCart` or `CustomerCartDto` class. That's because when a map is not defined for a property, AutoMapper will look for a identically named property in the source model and automatically map from it.